# Making a Seudah into a "Seudas Mitzvah"

Tags: halacha, chanuka, song-poetry, meal-seudah

The Rema in Hilchos Channukah [Siman 670 Sif 2](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49628&st=&pgnum=274) writes that if zemiros and shvachos (songs and praise) are said by a Seudah on Channukah it becomes a "Seudas Mitzvah" (without this it only has in it "katzas mitzvah" according to the Rema. Or according to the Machaber is a seudas reshus.) The M"A there in Sif-Katan Daled says so to by the marriage of a bas Talmud Chacham to an Am HaAretz if shiras are said then it becomes a seudas mitzvah. What about a seudah in general that is made in the middle of the week, at no special time of the year. If I get a few friends together and sing zemiros v'shvachos does the seudah become a seudas mitzvah? Or is it only when there is an "additional factor" or reason that in and of itself doesn't make the seuda a seudas mitzvah, only together with the singing would it become a seudas mitzvah that the status of the seudah can be turned over.

If it's yes only when there is an additional factor, then what would be more examples and what are the requirements exactly?

Comment: Lemai Nafka Minah?

Comment: @DoubleAA You are asking me this question? Or is the question directed at the Rema and all the poskim here that are telling you how to make a seuda into a seudas mitzvah (without giving a reason for this importance)? I'm trying to figure it out if there are other examples and what the criteria is. Perhaps the nafka mina however would be someone who only wants to eat by a seudas mitzvah and not a seudas reshus. (sources needed.)

Comment: It would be easier than making a siyum for Taanit Bechorim ;-)

Answer (score 6):

After introducing the basic reasons for Chanukah, the *Kitzur Shulchan Aruch* writes:

> ולכן י"א שמצוה להרבות קצת בסעודה בחנוכה, ועוד מפני שמלאכת המשכן נגמר בימים אלו, ויש לספר לב"ב ענין הניסים שנעשו לאבותנו בימים האלו, **ומ"מ לא הוי סעודת מצוה אא"כ אומרים בסעודה שירות ותשבחות**
>
> Therefore, some say that there is a *mitzva* to increase somewhat in feasting, and also because the work of the *mishkan* was completed at this time. A person should tell over to his household the miracles that happened for our ancestors during these days. **Nevertheless, it is not a *seudas mitzva* unless songs and praises are said by the meal.**

To me, this language seems to indicate that the "*songs and praises*" only serve as the final condition. Meaning, given all of the previously stated reasons for why a Chanuka *seudah* should be a *mitzva*, the "songs and praises" are what close the deal. However, without all of those previous reasons, an ordinary meal with "songs and praises" would not qualify as a *seudas mitzva*.

This conclusion also appears to be explicit in the *Mishneh Berurah* (670:9), in his comment on the Remah's statement that if the meal is accompanied with songs and praises "אז הוי סעודת מצוה" - "then it is a *seudas mitzva*":

> ואז הוי סעודת מצוה - **ר"ל בצרוף זה**. ... וכתב הרש"ל שכל שעושה כדי ליתן שבח למקום או לפרסם הנס או המצוה הכל סעודת מצוה
>
> "And this is is a *seudas mitva*" - Meaning, **in combination with this**. ... And the Maharshal writes that any [*seuda*] made to give praise to God, or to publicize the miracle, or to publicize the *mitzva*, is a *seudas mitzva*.

The statement, "in combination with this", seems to clearly indicate that songs and praises by themselves cannot make a meal into a *seudas mitzva*. It is only when they are combined with other factors.

As for the underlying reasoning behind this, it seems that the basic definition of a *seudas mitzva* is a meal that one is specifically supposed to eat in fulfillment of a *mitzva*. This includes all Shabbos and Yom Tov meals, as well as meals associated with other *mitzvos*, such as a *bris*, a *chasuna*, or a *siyum*. In all of these cases, there is a *mitzva*, and often an outright obligation, to participate in the *seudah*. In other words, for a meal to be a true *seudas mitzva*, the seudah must qualify intrinsically as a *mitzva* (i.e. the *mitzva* is to eat).

By this definition, it is obvious that an ordinary meal with friends cannot become a *seudas mitzva* simply by adding "songs and praises". While singing songs and praises of God at an ordinary meal may be a very praiseworthy, they would not make the meal itself into a *mitzva*.

Chanuka, however, is a rather ambiguous case. Since there is apparently no actual obligation to make a *seuda* on Chanuka, all Chanuka meals would be considered *seudas reshus*. However, being that there are sources that indicate it *is* a *mitzva* to feast on Chanuka, when a Chanuka meal is combined with other factors (i.e. publicizing the miracle and singing praises to God), we do consider it a *seudas mitzva*.

---

**Edit:**

I just looked up the [Maharshal in *Yam Shel Shlomo* (*Bava Kama* 7:37)](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=40932&st=&pgnum=150&hilite=). The Maharshal writes:

> אלא נראה כל סעודה שאדם עושה שלא כדרך מריעות ושמחה, אלא כדי ליתן שבח למקום או לפרסם המצוה או לפרסם הנס קרוי סעודת מצוה, כגון פדיון הבן לפרסם המצוה
>
> Rather, it seems that any *seudah* that a person makes, not in the manner of friendship and rejoicing, but for the purpose of giving praise to God, or to publicize [the performance of] a *mitzva*, or to publicize a miracle, is called a *seudas mitzva*, such as [the *seuda* by] a *pidyon haben*, which is to publicize a *mitzva*.

The Maharshal appears to be saying that everything depends on the purpose of the meal. This is not fully in agreement with the approach I presented above. I argued that there needs to be some intrinsic aspect of *mitzva* in the meal, but the Maharshal is saying that one can indeed simply create a *seudas mitzva*. However, even according to the Maharshal, the purpose of the meal must be the *mitzva*. One cannot simply convert an ordinary meal into a *seudas mitzva* by including praises of God.

Incidentally, the Maharshal also states, later in the same discussion, that there is a *mitzva* of *seudah* on Chanuka, and the *seudos* of Chanuka are *seudos mitzva* in their own right.

Comment: You wrote: "The statement, 'in combination with this', seems to clearly indicate that songs and praises by themselves cannot make a meal into a seudas mitzva. It is only when they are combined with other factors." It seems to me that the Mishnah Brurah is saying this but then saying "But the Rashal says otherwise."

Comment: @ba I'm not quite following your point (especially in light of the addendum I added discussing the Maharshal). The MB's statement, "in combination", is explaining the Rema's position, that given the other factors, a Chanuka seudah with songs and praises qualifies a seudas mitzva. The MB then reinforces this opinion with the concept from the Maharshal that any meal specifically made for the purpose of praising God qualifies as a seudas mitzva. The Maharshal himself, of course, as I mentioned above, holds that any Chanuka seuda is a seudas mitzva (unlike the Rema).

Answer (score 2):

The [Mishnah Brurah 9](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49628&st=&pgnum=274) says in the name of Maharshal that any meal made for the purpose of publicizing a mitzvah or to give praise to Hashem is a se'udas mitzvah.

Comment: I believe the Maharshal's statement is specifically referring to Chanuka meals. (See my discussion in the answer I just submitted.)

Comment: Actually, having looked up the Maharshal inside, my above comment is incorrect. Nevertheless, the Maharshal is still not saying that "any meal with praises is a se'udas mitzvah." The Maharshal writes (YSS BK 7:37):
אלא נראה כל סעודה שאדם עושה שלא כדרך מריעות ושמחה, אלא כדי ליתן שבח למקום או לפרסם המצוה או לפרסם הנס קרוי סעודת מצוה, כגון פדיון הבן לפרסם המצוה
It is clear that the Maharshal requires that the *purpose* of the meal must be for a mitzva. An ordinary meal with praises would not qualify.

Comment: @LazerA I changed it according to your comment (and it is in truth what the Mishnah Brurah actually says, just that it was such a subtle difference that I didn't pay enough attention at first to realize)

Answer (score 1):

According to the rabbis and the Rav that I learned from, one cannot simply declare a seudat mitzvah by including praises of HaShem. We praise HaShem anyways when we bentsch. Even Rosh Chodesh meals are not considered seudat mitzvot according to my Rav.